# Unable to get GAE logging to work: "Failed to load"

Tags: google-app-engine

After receiving a page with the error message "The server encountered an error and could not complete your request" I attempted to view my log in the Google Developer's Console(https://console.developers.google.com/logs?project=myapplication&authuser=1) and go the message "Failed to load".

How can I view my log?

Comment: I see the same,  probably some recent bug/issue on GAE side.

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved  now...